# Если QLineEdit пуст, то приложение крашится

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Код на `Python`, с использованием библиотеки `PyQt5`. Написал калькулятор суточного расхода калорий, всё работает, но есть проблема.

Если `QLineEdit` или `QLineEdit`'ы пусты, то приложение крашится.
Прошу помочь

**main.py**:

```
import re
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from design_project import Ui_MainWindow

OLDEST_HUMAN = 112
MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC = 7
GREATEST_WEIGHT = 635
MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC = 20
HIGHEST_GROWTH = 272
LOWEST_GROWTH = 55
MAX_EXP = 14241
MIN_EXP = 417


class WayToTheDream(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Way To The Dream!')
        self.setFixedSize(1010, 763)
        # условия для запуска  | калькулятор
        self.LineVivodCalc.setDisabled(True)
        self.PolMuzh.stateChanged.connect(self.calculating_if_polmuzh)
        self.PolZhen.stateChanged.connect(self.calculating_if_polzhen)
        # лимит на количество символов в лайнэдитах + возможность вводить только цифры
        self.LineRost.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 999))
        self.LineVes.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 999))
        self.LineVozrast.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 999))
        self.lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 99999))

    # проверка на соблюдение условий В КАЛЬКУЛЯТОРЕ СУТОЧНОГО РАСХОДА КАЛОРИЙ если пользователь выбрал МУЖСКОЙ ПОЛ
    def checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh(self):
        string_vozrast1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineVozrast.text())))))
        if MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC <= string_vozrast1 <= OLDEST_HUMAN:
            string_ves1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineVes.text())))))
            if GREATEST_WEIGHT >= string_ves1 >= MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC:
                string_rost1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineRost.text())))))
                if HIGHEST_GROWTH >= string_rost1 >= LOWEST_GROWTH:
                    return 5 + (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                            5 * string_vozrast1)

    # проверка на соблюдение условий В КАЛЬКУЛЯТОРЕ СУТОЧНОГО РАСХОДА КАЛОРИЙ если пользователь выбрал ЖЕНСКИЙ ПОЛ
    def checking_for_a_condition_polzhen(self):
        string_vozrast1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineVozrast.text())))))
        if MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC <= string_vozrast1 <= OLDEST_HUMAN:
            string_ves1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineVes.text())))))
            if GREATEST_WEIGHT >= string_ves1 >= MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC:
                string_rost1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineRost.text())))))
                if HIGHEST_GROWTH >= string_rost1 >= LOWEST_GROWTH:
                    return (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                            5 * string_vozrast1) - 161

    # вывод суточного расхода калорий если пользователь выбрал МУЖСКОЙ ПОЛ
    def calculating_if_polmuzh(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(False)
            if self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() is None:
                self.LineVivodCalc.clear()
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Сидячий':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.2) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Слабый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.375) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Преобладает физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.55) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.725) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Очень тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.9) + ' ккал/сут.')
        else:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(True)
            self.LineVivodCalc.clear()

    # вывод суточного расхода калорий если пользователь выбрал ЖЕНСКИЙ ПОЛ
    def calculating_if_polzhen(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(False)
            if self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() is None:
                self.LineVivodCalc.clear()
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Сидячий':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.2) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Слабый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.375) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Преобладает физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.55) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.725) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Очень тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.9) + ' ккал/сут.')
        else:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(True)
            self.LineVivodCalc.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = WayToTheDream()
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**design_project.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1010, 763)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.ViborPola = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ViborPola.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 320, 81, 51))
        self.ViborPola.setObjectName("ViborPola")
        self.PolMuzh = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.PolMuzh.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 320, 70, 17))
        self.PolMuzh.setObjectName("PolMuzh")
        self.PolZhen = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.PolZhen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 350, 70, 17))
        self.PolZhen.setObjectName("PolZhen")
        self.UkazatVozrast = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatVozrast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 150, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatVozrast.setObjectName("UkazatVozrast")
        self.LineVozrast = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineVozrast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 150, 71, 51))
        self.LineVozrast.setObjectName("LineVozrast")
        self.UkazatVes = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatVes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 200, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatVes.setObjectName("UkazatVes")
        self.LineVes = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineVes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 200, 71, 51))
        self.LineVes.setObjectName("LineVes")
        self.UkazatRost = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatRost.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 250, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatRost.setObjectName("UkazatRost")
        self.LineRost = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineRost.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 250, 71, 51))
        self.LineRost.setObjectName("LineRost")
        self.LvlFizAkt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.LvlFizAkt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 50, 171, 21))
        self.LvlFizAkt.setObjectName("LvlFizAkt")
        self.ComboFizAkt = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ComboFizAkt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 70, 171, 22))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setObjectName("ComboFizAkt")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.KolvoTrenirovok = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 100, 171, 21))
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setObjectName("KolvoTrenirovok")
        self.ComboTrenirovki = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 120, 171, 22))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setObjectName("ComboTrenirovki")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.LineVivodCalc = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineVivodCalc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 370, 171, 91))
        self.LineVivodCalc.setObjectName("LineVivodCalc")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1010, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.ViborPola.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пол"))
        self.PolMuzh.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мужской"))
        self.PolZhen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Женский"))
        self.UkazatVozrast.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Возраст"))
        self.UkazatVes.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вес"))
        self.UkazatRost.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Рост"))
        self.LvlFizAkt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Уровень физической активности:"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Сидячий"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Слабый физ. труд"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Преобладает физ. труд"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Тяжёлый физ. труд"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Очень тяжёлый физ. труд"))
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кол-во тренировок в неделю:"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "7+"))
```

**P.S.**
Добавлена проверка, но всё равно происходит ошибка:

```
    def calculating_if_polmuzh(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(False)
            if self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() is None:
                self.LineVivodCalc.clear()
            if not self.LineVozrast.text():  # начало
                self.LineVivodCalc.clear()
            if not self.LineVes.text():
                self.LineVivodCalc.clear()
            if not self.LineRost.text():
                self.LineVivodCalc.clear()  # конец
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Сидячий':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.2) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Слабый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.375) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Преобладает физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.55) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.725) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Очень тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.9) + ' ккал/сут.')
        else:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(True)
            self.LineVivodCalc.clear()
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'WayToTheDream' object has no attribute 'lineEdit'` в `self.lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 99999))`?

Comment: Кст, а нафига вам QLIneEdit для чисел? Используйте QSpinBox, он для этого был сделан

Comment: Убрал ту строку, запустил, нажал на чекбокс и получил ошибку `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`. Я то думал у вас крашится без стека (такое замечал в qt), могли бы сэкономить время и добавить в вопрос трассу стека

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо вставить проверку, например так:

```
...

def checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh(self):
    if not self.LineVozrast.text():                             # +
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(                # +
            self, "Внимание!", "Введите какие-нибудь данные.")  # +
        return                                                  # +

...
```

---

**Update**

я же написал как пример, а вам видимо надо проверить все QLineEdit'ы. Проверьте так:

```
...

def checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh(self):
    if (not self.LineVozrast.text()) or \
       (not self.LineVes.text()) or \
       (not self.LineRost.text())  :
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            self, "Внимание!", "Введите какие-нибудь данные.")
        return
...
```

---

**Update 2**

Я добавил для вас некоторую проверку, а также немного упорядочил ваши методы `calculating_if_polmuzh` и `calculating_if_polzhen` , попробуйте:

```
import sys
import re
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

#from design_project import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1010, 763)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.ViborPola = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ViborPola.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 320, 81, 51))
        self.ViborPola.setObjectName("ViborPola")
        self.PolMuzh = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.PolMuzh.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 320, 70, 17))
        self.PolMuzh.setObjectName("PolMuzh")
        self.PolZhen = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.PolZhen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 350, 70, 17))
        self.PolZhen.setObjectName("PolZhen")
        self.UkazatVozrast = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatVozrast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 150, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatVozrast.setObjectName("UkazatVozrast")
        self.LineVozrast = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)       
        self.LineVozrast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 150, 71, 51))
        self.LineVozrast.setObjectName("LineVozrast")
        self.UkazatVes = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatVes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 200, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatVes.setObjectName("UkazatVes")
        self.LineVes = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineVes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 200, 71, 51))
        self.LineVes.setObjectName("LineVes")
        self.UkazatRost = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatRost.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 250, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatRost.setObjectName("UkazatRost")
        self.LineRost = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineRost.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 250, 71, 51))
        self.LineRost.setObjectName("LineRost")
        self.LvlFizAkt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.LvlFizAkt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 50, 171, 21))
        self.LvlFizAkt.setObjectName("LvlFizAkt")
        self.ComboFizAkt = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ComboFizAkt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 70, 171, 22))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setObjectName("ComboFizAkt")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.KolvoTrenirovok = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 100, 171, 21))
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setObjectName("KolvoTrenirovok")
        self.ComboTrenirovki = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 120, 171, 22))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setObjectName("ComboTrenirovki")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.LineVivodCalc = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineVivodCalc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 370, 171, 91))
        self.LineVivodCalc.setObjectName("LineVivodCalc")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1010, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.ViborPola.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пол"))
        self.PolMuzh.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мужской"))
        self.PolZhen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Женский"))
        self.UkazatVozrast.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Возраст"))
        self.UkazatVes.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вес"))
        self.UkazatRost.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Рост"))
        self.LvlFizAkt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Уровень физической активности:"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Сидячий"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Слабый физ. труд"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Преобладает физ. труд"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Тяжёлый физ. труд"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Очень тяжёлый физ. труд"))
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кол-во тренировок в неделю:"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "7+"))


OLDEST_HUMAN = 112
MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC = 7
GREATEST_WEIGHT = 635
MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC = 20
HIGHEST_GROWTH = 272
LOWEST_GROWTH = 55
MAX_EXP = 14241
MIN_EXP = 417


class WayToTheDream(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.setWindowTitle('Way To The Dream!')
        self.setFixedSize(1010, 763)
        # условия для запуска  | калькулятор
        self.LineVivodCalc.setDisabled(True)
        self.PolMuzh.stateChanged.connect(self.calculating_if_polmuzh)
        self.PolZhen.stateChanged.connect(self.calculating_if_polzhen)
        # лимит на количество символов в лайнэдитах + возможность вводить только цифры
        self.LineRost.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 999))
        self.LineVes.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 999))
        self.LineVozrast.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 999))
        
# ?       self.lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 99999))       # ????????????????

    def checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh(self):
        """ проверка на соблюдение условий В КАЛЬКУЛЯТОРЕ СРК, МУЖСКОЙ ПОЛ """
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        if (not self.LineVozrast.text()) or \
           (not self.LineVes.text()) or \
           (not self.LineRost.text())  :
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, "Внимание!", "Введите Возраст, Вес и Рост.")
            return False
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
        string_vozrast1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineVozrast.text())))))
        if MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC <= string_vozrast1 <= OLDEST_HUMAN:
            string_ves1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineVes.text())))))
            if GREATEST_WEIGHT >= string_ves1 >= MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC:
                string_rost1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineRost.text())))))
                if HIGHEST_GROWTH >= string_rost1 >= LOWEST_GROWTH:
                    return 5 + (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                            5 * string_vozrast1)
        return False # +                            

    def checking_for_a_condition_polzhen(self):
        """ проверка на соблюдение условий В КАЛЬКУЛЯТОРЕ СРК, ЖЕНСКИЙ ПОЛ """    
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        if (not self.LineVozrast.text()) or \
           (not self.LineVes.text()) or \
           (not self.LineRost.text())  :
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, "Внимание!", "Введите Возраст, Вес и Рост.")
            return False
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
        string_vozrast1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineVozrast.text())))))
        if MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC <= string_vozrast1 <= OLDEST_HUMAN:
            string_ves1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineVes.text())))))
            if GREATEST_WEIGHT >= string_ves1 >= MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC:
                string_rost1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineRost.text())))))
                if HIGHEST_GROWTH >= string_rost1 >= LOWEST_GROWTH:
                    return (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                            5 * string_vozrast1) - 161
        return False # +

    # вывод суточного расхода калорий если пользователь выбрал МУЖСКОЙ ПОЛ
    def calculating_if_polmuzh(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(False)
            rez_calc_polmuzh = self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh()
            if not rez_calc_polmuzh: 
#                self.LineVivodCalc.clear()
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(f'Результата: HET.') 
                return                         # Если резельтата нет, то дальше ничего не делаем
                
            comboFizAkt = self.ComboFizAkt.currentText()
            if comboFizAkt == 'Сидячий':
                rez = rez_calc_polmuzh * 1.2
            elif comboFizAkt == 'Слабый физ. труд':
                rez = rez_calc_polmuzh * 1.375
            elif comboFizAkt == 'Преобладает физ. труд':
                rez = rez_calc_polmuzh * 1.55
            elif comboFizAkt == 'Тяжёлый физ. труд':
                rez = rez_calc_polmuzh * 1.725
            elif comboFizAkt == 'Очень тяжёлый физ. труд':
                rez = rez_calc_polmuzh * 1.9 
            self.LineVivodCalc.setText(f'Результат: {rez:>8.2f} ккал/сут.')    
        else:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(True)
            self.LineVivodCalc.clear()

    # вывод суточного расхода калорий если пользователь выбрал ЖЕНСКИЙ ПОЛ
    def calculating_if_polzhen(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(False)
            rez_calc_polmuzh = self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen()
            if not rez_calc_polmuzh: 
#                self.LineVivodCalc.clear()
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(f'Результата: HET.') 
                return                         # Если резельтата нет, то дальше ничего не делаем
                
            comboFizAkt = self.ComboFizAkt.currentText()
            if comboFizAkt == 'Сидячий':
                rez = rez_calc_polmuzh * 1.2
            elif comboFizAkt == 'Слабый физ. труд':
                rez = rez_calc_polmuzh * 1.375
            elif comboFizAkt == 'Преобладает физ. труд':
                rez = rez_calc_polmuzh * 1.55
            elif comboFizAkt == 'Тяжёлый физ. труд':
                rez = rez_calc_polmuzh * 1.725
            elif comboFizAkt == 'Очень тяжёлый физ. труд':
                rez = rez_calc_polmuzh * 1.9 
            self.LineVivodCalc.setText(f'Результат: {rez:>8.2f} ккал/сут.')    
        else:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(True)
            self.LineVivodCalc.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = WayToTheDream()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавил проверку, ошибка осталась, код добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Diazz добавьте полный текст ошибки и укажите какие действия вы делаете, чтобы получить ошибку.

Comment: @Diazz, а на мой ответ не отреагировали и для кого старался :)

Comment: @S.Nick  я не вводя никакие данные в лайн эдиты нажимаю на чекбоксы. Приложение просто крашится

Comment: @Diazz хорошо, я посмотрю ваше приложение еще раз.

Comment: @Diazz я обновил свой ответ, проверьте.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка из-за того, что в `int` у вас была пустая строка

> ```
> string_vozrast1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineVozrast.text())))))
>     ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
> ```

У вас тот код повторяется и лучше его в функцию поместить примерно так:

*Кст, у вас в функции излишек кода. Смотрите, `findall` и так возвращает список строку, поэтому `map` с `str` излишен, поэтому убрал лишнее*

```
def get_int(line_edit) -> int:
    try:
        return int("".join(re.findall(r'\d+', line_edit.text())))
    except:
        return -1
```

Тогда, с функцией код станет таким:

```
string_vozrast1 = get_int(self.LineVozrast)
```

С куском кода:

```
    # проверка на соблюдение условий В КАЛЬКУЛЯТОРЕ СУТОЧНОГО РАСХОДА КАЛОРИЙ если пользователь выбрал МУЖСКОЙ ПОЛ
    def checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh(self):
        string_vozrast1 = get_int(self.LineVozrast)
        #                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC <= string_vozrast1 <= OLDEST_HUMAN:
            string_ves1 = get_int(self.LineVes)
            #             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            if GREATEST_WEIGHT >= string_ves1 >= MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC:
                string_rost1 = get_int(self.LineRost)
                #              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                if HIGHEST_GROWTH >= string_rost1 >= LOWEST_GROWTH:
                    return 5 + (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                            5 * string_vozrast1)

    # проверка на соблюдение условий В КАЛЬКУЛЯТОРЕ СУТОЧНОГО РАСХОДА КАЛОРИЙ если пользователь выбрал ЖЕНСКИЙ ПОЛ
    def checking_for_a_condition_polzhen(self):
        string_vozrast1 = get_int(self.LineVozrast)
        #                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC <= string_vozrast1 <= OLDEST_HUMAN:
            string_ves1 = get_int(self.LineVes)
            #             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            if GREATEST_WEIGHT >= string_ves1 >= MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC:
                string_rost1 = get_int(self.LineRost)
                #              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                if HIGHEST_GROWTH >= string_rost1 >= LOWEST_GROWTH:
                    return (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                            5 * string_vozrast1) - 161
```

Весь **main.py**:

```
import re
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from design_project import Ui_MainWindow


def get_int(line_edit) -> int:
    try:
        return int("".join(re.findall(r'\d+', line_edit.text())))
    except:
        return -1


OLDEST_HUMAN = 112
MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC = 7
GREATEST_WEIGHT = 635
MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC = 20
HIGHEST_GROWTH = 272
LOWEST_GROWTH = 55
MAX_EXP = 14241
MIN_EXP = 417


class WayToTheDream(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Way To The Dream!')
        self.setFixedSize(1010, 763)
        # условия для запуска  | калькулятор
        self.LineVivodCalc.setDisabled(True)
        self.PolMuzh.stateChanged.connect(self.calculating_if_polmuzh)
        self.PolZhen.stateChanged.connect(self.calculating_if_polzhen)
        # лимит на количество символов в лайнэдитах + возможность вводить только цифры
        self.LineRost.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 999))
        self.LineVes.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 999))
        self.LineVozrast.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 999))
        # self.lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 99999))

        # проверка на соблюдение условий В КАЛЬКУЛЯТОРЕ СУТОЧНОГО РАСХОДА КАЛОРИЙ если пользователь выбрал МУЖСКОЙ ПОЛ

    def checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh(self):
        string_vozrast1 = get_int(self.LineVozrast)
        if MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC <= string_vozrast1 <= OLDEST_HUMAN:
            string_ves1 = get_int(self.LineVes)
            if GREATEST_WEIGHT >= string_ves1 >= MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC:
                string_rost1 = get_int(self.LineRost)
                if HIGHEST_GROWTH >= string_rost1 >= LOWEST_GROWTH:
                    return 5 + (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                            5 * string_vozrast1)

    # проверка на соблюдение условий В КАЛЬКУЛЯТОРЕ СУТОЧНОГО РАСХОДА КАЛОРИЙ если пользователь выбрал ЖЕНСКИЙ ПОЛ
    def checking_for_a_condition_polzhen(self):
        string_vozrast1 = get_int(self.LineVozrast)
        if MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC <= string_vozrast1 <= OLDEST_HUMAN:
            string_ves1 = get_int(self.LineVes)
            if GREATEST_WEIGHT >= string_ves1 >= MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC:
                string_rost1 = get_int(self.LineRost)
                if HIGHEST_GROWTH >= string_rost1 >= LOWEST_GROWTH:
                    return (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                            5 * string_vozrast1) - 161

    # вывод суточного расхода калорий если пользователь выбрал МУЖСКОЙ ПОЛ
    def calculating_if_polmuzh(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(False)
            if self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() is None:
                self.LineVivodCalc.clear()
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Сидячий':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.2) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Слабый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.375) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Преобладает физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.55) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.725) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Очень тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.9) + ' ккал/сут.')
        else:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(True)
            self.LineVivodCalc.clear()

        # вывод суточного расхода калорий если пользователь выбрал ЖЕНСКИЙ ПОЛ

    def calculating_if_polzhen(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(False)
            if self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() is None:
                self.LineVivodCalc.clear()
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Сидячий':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.2) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Слабый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.375) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Преобладает физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.55) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.725) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Очень тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.9) + ' ккал/сут.')
        else:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(True)
            self.LineVivodCalc.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = WayToTheDream()
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

### НО!

Я вам рекомендую не писать костыли с `QLineEdit`, а вместо них использовать [QSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#details). Этот виджет как раз то, что вам нужно и вы сможете сразу работать с целыми числами и получать из него числа (метод `value`)

**UPD.** Пример с этим решением [в соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1226347/201445)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы избавился от `QLineEdit` в пользу `QSpinBox`, это решит проблему и упростит код, плюс интерфейс станет дружелюбнее. Причем, для этого нужно не нужно переписывать всё – нужно в нескольких местах поменять код, а в дизайнере на место `QLineEdit` поместить `QSpinBox` с такимим же `object name`.

После замены на `QSpinBox` работает и теперь выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*Выделил комментариями c `^^^^^^^` места, где поменял*

**main.py:**

```
import re
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from design_project import Ui_MainWindow


OLDEST_HUMAN = 112
MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC = 7
GREATEST_WEIGHT = 635
MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC = 20
HIGHEST_GROWTH = 272
LOWEST_GROWTH = 55
MAX_EXP = 14241
MIN_EXP = 417


class WayToTheDream(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Way To The Dream!')
        self.setFixedSize(1010, 763)
        # условия для запуска  | калькулятор
        self.LineVivodCalc.setDisabled(True)
        self.PolMuzh.stateChanged.connect(self.calculating_if_polmuzh)
        self.PolZhen.stateChanged.connect(self.calculating_if_polzhen)
        # лимит на количество символов в лайнэдитах + возможность вводить только цифры

        # self.LineRost.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 999))
        # self.LineVes.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 999))
        # self.LineVozrast.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 999))
        # self.lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(1, 99999))
        self.LineRost.setRange(LOWEST_GROWTH, HIGHEST_GROWTH)
        self.LineVes.setRange(MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC, GREATEST_WEIGHT)
        self.LineVozrast.setRange(MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC, OLDEST_HUMAN)
        #             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    # проверка на соблюдение условий В КАЛЬКУЛЯТОРЕ СУТОЧНОГО РАСХОДА КАЛОРИЙ если пользователь выбрал МУЖСКОЙ ПОЛ
    def checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh(self):
        # string_vozrast1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineVozrast.text())))))
        string_vozrast1 = self.LineVozrast.value()
        #             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC <= string_vozrast1 <= OLDEST_HUMAN:
            # string_ves1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineVes.text())))))
            string_ves1 = self.LineVes.value()
            #             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            if GREATEST_WEIGHT >= string_ves1 >= MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC:
                # string_rost1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineRost.text())))))
                string_rost1 = self.LineRost.value()
                #             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                if HIGHEST_GROWTH >= string_rost1 >= LOWEST_GROWTH:
                    return 5 + (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                            5 * string_vozrast1)

    # проверка на соблюдение условий В КАЛЬКУЛЯТОРЕ СУТОЧНОГО РАСХОДА КАЛОРИЙ если пользователь выбрал ЖЕНСКИЙ ПОЛ
    def checking_for_a_condition_polzhen(self):
        # string_vozrast1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineVozrast.text())))))
        string_vozrast1 = self.LineVozrast.value()
        #             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if MIN_AGE_FOR_CALC <= string_vozrast1 <= OLDEST_HUMAN:
            # string_ves1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineVes.text())))))
            string_ves1 = self.LineVes.value()
            #             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            if GREATEST_WEIGHT >= string_ves1 >= MIN_WEIGHT_FOR_CALC:
                # string_rost1 = int("".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', self.LineRost.text())))))
                string_rost1 = self.LineRost.value()
                #             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                if HIGHEST_GROWTH >= string_rost1 >= LOWEST_GROWTH:
                    return (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                            5 * string_vozrast1) - 161

    # вывод суточного расхода калорий если пользователь выбрал МУЖСКОЙ ПОЛ
    def calculating_if_polmuzh(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(False)
            if self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() is None:
                self.LineVivodCalc.clear()
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Сидячий':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.2) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Слабый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.375) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Преобладает физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.55) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.725) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Очень тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polmuzh() * 1.9) + ' ккал/сут.')
        else:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(True)
            self.LineVivodCalc.clear()

        # вывод суточного расхода калорий если пользователь выбрал ЖЕНСКИЙ ПОЛ

    def calculating_if_polzhen(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(False)
            if self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() is None:
                self.LineVivodCalc.clear()
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Сидячий':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.2) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Слабый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.375) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Преобладает физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.55) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.725) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Очень тяжёлый физ. труд':
                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(self.checking_for_a_condition_polzhen() * 1.9) + ' ккал/сут.')
        else:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(True)
            self.LineVivodCalc.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = WayToTheDream()
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**design_project.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1010, 763)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.ViborPola = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ViborPola.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 320, 81, 51))
        self.ViborPola.setObjectName("ViborPola")
        self.PolMuzh = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.PolMuzh.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 320, 70, 17))
        self.PolMuzh.setObjectName("PolMuzh")
        self.PolZhen = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.PolZhen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 350, 70, 17))
        self.PolZhen.setObjectName("PolZhen")
        self.UkazatVozrast = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatVozrast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 150, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatVozrast.setObjectName("UkazatVozrast")
        self.LineVozrast = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        #                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.LineVozrast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 150, 71, 51))
        self.LineVozrast.setObjectName("LineVozrast")
        self.UkazatVes = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatVes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 200, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatVes.setObjectName("UkazatVes")
        self.LineVes = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        #                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.LineVes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 200, 71, 51))
        self.LineVes.setObjectName("LineVes")
        self.UkazatRost = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatRost.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 250, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatRost.setObjectName("UkazatRost")
        self.LineRost = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        #                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.LineRost.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 250, 71, 51))
        self.LineRost.setObjectName("LineRost")
        self.LvlFizAkt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.LvlFizAkt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 50, 171, 21))
        self.LvlFizAkt.setObjectName("LvlFizAkt")
        self.ComboFizAkt = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ComboFizAkt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 70, 171, 22))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setObjectName("ComboFizAkt")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.KolvoTrenirovok = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 100, 171, 21))
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setObjectName("KolvoTrenirovok")
        self.ComboTrenirovki = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 120, 171, 22))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setObjectName("ComboTrenirovki")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.LineVivodCalc = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineVivodCalc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 370, 171, 91))
        self.LineVivodCalc.setObjectName("LineVivodCalc")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1010, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.ViborPola.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пол"))
        self.PolMuzh.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мужской"))
        self.PolZhen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Женский"))
        self.UkazatVozrast.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Возраст"))
        self.UkazatVes.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вес"))
        self.UkazatRost.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Рост"))
        self.LvlFizAkt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Уровень физической активности:"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Сидячий"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Слабый физ. труд"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Преобладает физ. труд"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Тяжёлый физ. труд"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Очень тяжёлый физ. труд"))
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кол-во тренировок в неделю:"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "7+"))
```

---

**PS.**

Советую, виджеты размещать на компоновщиках (`layout`, типа `QVBoxLayout`, `QHBoxLayout`, `QGridLayout`, ...), тогда не придется вручную размещать и менять размер виджетов, да и они будут растягиваться вместе с окном. Компоновщики есть в `Qt Designer`

Comment: Спасибо, тоже вариант, но мне нужен именно QLineEdit

Comment: @Diazz, странное требование, тогда попробуйте мой вариант с функцией `get_int` ;)

Comment: у меня всё работает, просто если лайнэдиты пусты и нажать на чекбокс с выбором пола, программа крашится

Comment: @Diazz, ну ок, а что насчет другого моего ответа с `get_int`? **Я проверил она работает, нажал чекбокс при пустых и ошибок нет, код не крашится.** Поменял код как было показано, ввел минимальные значения и калории вывелись. Меня смущает, что я вам два ответа с решением показал, а вы ни тот, ни другой не хотите принимать :) Ладно, с QSpinBox вам не нравится, а чем не нравится другой ответ просто не понимаю :)